# Why is the ajax request without the app name?

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, java-web-start

It is my Graduation Project，I have some server end knowledge. But I am not familiar with JS. If I don't add context-path (I mean project name), it will run without any problem. But If I add some context-path, some ajax request will return `404`. I have tried debug（alter）some `js` code. But it seems in the vain.

I have altered url of `'fLike'` and `'fDislike'`, I added `'/itnews'` before the url.

```
(function (window, undefined) {
    var Action = Base.createClass('main.util.Action');
    $.extend(Action, {
        like: fLike,
        dislike: fDislike,
        post: fPost
    });

    function fLike(oConf) {
        var that = this;
        that.post({
            url: '/itnews/like',
            data: {newsId: oConf.newsId},
            call: oConf.call,
            error: oConf.error,
            always: oConf.always
        });
    }

    function fDislike(oConf) {
        var that = this;
        that.post({
            url: '/itnews/dislike',
            data: {newsId: oConf.newsId},
            call: oConf.call,
            error: oConf.error,
            always: oConf.always
        });
    }

    function fPost(oConf) {
        var that = this;
        $.ajax({
            method: oConf.method || 'POST',
            url: oConf.url,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: oConf.data
        }).done(function (oResult) {
            var nCode = oResult.code;
            nCode === 0 && oConf.call && oConf.call(oResult);
            nCode !== 0 && oConf.error && oConf.error(oResult);
        }).fail(oConf.error).always(oConf.always);
    }
})(window);
```

This is `'application.yml'`

```
spring:
  freemarker:
    template-loader-path: classpath:/templates/
    cache: false
    charset: UTF-8
    check-template-location: true
    content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    expose-request-attributes: true
    expose-session-attributes: true
    request-context-attribute: request
    datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/news?serverTimezone=GMT&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    username: root
    password: 123456
    type: com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource
    server:
    servlet:
    context-path: /itnews
    port: 8080
```

When I click `'like'`, It returns 404( Request URL: `http://localhost:8080/like` ),It has no application name. Why?

I am posting some picture about this:

[e1](https://it-news.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com/1.png)
[e2](https://it-news.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com/2.png)
[e404](https://it-news.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com/404.png)

Comment: Are you saying that if you have no specific context path (or a context path of just / ) then requesting something like `/like` works but specifying a context path and then requesting `/yourContextPath/like` does not work ?

Comment: yes， I plan to deploy it to my vps. So，I think the context-path is necessity(I need make my project into `xxx.war`, and then put it into /tomcat/webapps) .  But If I specifying `js` code, It doesn't work.